# How to check if minification went wrong?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, minify

I have a `resolve` in my code which works perfectly fine locally and all tests pass as well. However, it seems that the minified code causes some problems here.

When I stage the code and then run it locally it causes the same issues as the minified code. The resolve block does not do its job anymore.

Is there a way to compare the minified code with the actual code to find differences?

```
.state('index', {
          url: '/',
          resolve: {
            trans: ['resolveService', function(resolveService) {
              resolveService.languageResolve('main', {});
            }]
          },
          controller: 'IndexCtrl'
        })
        .state('main', {
          url: '/{language:[a-z]{2}}',
          templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',

          controller: 'MainCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'mainCtrl',
          resolve: {
            trans: ['resolveService', '$stateParams', function(resolveService, $stateParams) {
              return resolveService.translateResolve($stateParams);
            }],
            redirect: ['resolveService', function(resolveService) {
              return resolveService.resolveRedirect();
            }]
          }
        })
        .state('main.results', {
          url: '/results/{route:nonURIEncoded}',
          templateUrl: 'app/results/results.wrapper.html',
          controller: 'ResultsCtrl',
          resolve: {
            urlParsed: ['urlParser','$stateParams','$state',function(urlParser,$stateParams,$state){
              return urlParser.parse($stateParams.route).then(function(){ return true },function(err){
                $state.go('main',{
                  language: $stateParams.language
                });
              });
            }]
          },
          controllerAs: 'rc'
        })
```

Comment: You could try to use the expand functionality in Chrome. If you get to the source in the Chrome console and click the expand brackets button this will at least restore the code to something like your original to rule this out.

Comment: @PeterS thanks for the hint. I'll try that

Comment: Yeah, You should give a try using `pretiffy` version in browser developer tools, this is available in both chrome as well as mozilla console window, just go to sources, click on your js file, if minified, it'll itself show an option below to preftiffy it, with this icon `{}`. Then you can try testing it with using breakpoints in it.
check here- https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks#prettyprint-javascript

Comment: Just found it. Thanks to both of you

Comment: What are you using to minify your code? When I was looking for disparitiies and checking what the minification process did, i passed individual files through the minification command line tool. I think we used ngAnnotate to automatically make our files minification compliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are experiencing a different behavior comparing the original and minified code, I'm pretty sure that something went wrong at the minification process and the result is incomplete or wrongly parsed. You should check your browser console and your minifier log for errors.

Also, as already pointed in comments ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998995/how-to-check-if-minification-went-wrong#comment61551291_36998995), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998995/how-to-check-if-minification-went-wrong#comment61551954_36998995)), you can pretty print the minified code to manually check where is the difference.

[In Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks#prettyprint-javascript):

> **Pretty Print JavaScript**
>
> The DevTools support prettifying of minified JavaScript to a more
>   readable form. To pretty print:
>
> - Go to the Sources panel and selected your desired script from the scripts list.
> - Next, press the "Pretty print" button  (marked with curly braces) from the bottom of the DevTools window.
> - Your code should now be prettified!
>
> Before
>
> [image: before]
>
> After
>
> [image: after]